# Some Questions on Covering maps.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to know a few things about covering spaces/maps.  First of all, it is true that covering maps induce injective homomorphisms between fundamental groups.  Is it also true that covering maps produce injective homomorphisms between 1st homology groups?  Also, is it true that covering maps preserve orientation whenever the two spaces in question are manifolds?

Comment: The first homology group of $\Bbb R$ is zero, while the first homology group of the circle $\Bbb S^1$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, so injectivity fails in homology.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, that example trivially satisfies injectivity...

Comment: The question essentially comes down to if a homomorphism $h:G \rightarrow H$ is injective, is $h^{ab}:G^{ab} \rightarrow H^{ab}$ injective?

Comment: @ChrisGerig Indeed, I got confused ^^

Comment: Take $C_4$ inside $D_8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Covering maps **do** induce injective maps on the first homotopy groups.

Covering maps **don't** induce injective maps on the first homology groups.

For a counterexample, considering the double cover $\mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{T}^2$ is the torus, and $\mathbb{K}$ is the Klein bottle.

This example also shows you can have an orientable manifold covering a non-orientable one.

You cannot, however, have a non-orientable manifold covering an orientable one. [Essentially, the "local homeomoprhism" nature of a covering allows one to lift the orientation from the target to the covering space.]